# I'm unable to set the right toggle effect to the button with a bootstrap class

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I've started learning jquery lately and this is what I'm trying to do:
I've added a click event to the button selector(by tag name), just to perform a simple toggle of the text and class.

The text part works fine using a conditional statement but if I try to toggle the class between btn-danger and btn-success, I'm unable to set it properly and couldn't figure out what to change.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="inner">
                <h4>Topic Heading</h4>
                <p>This is the first paragraph in the topic.</p>
                <p>This is the second paragraph in the topic.</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Hide</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("button").click(function (){
                    $("#inner").toggle("slow");
                    if ($(this).text() == "Hide") {
                        $(this).toggleClass("btn btn-success");
                        $(this).text("Show");
                    } 
                    else { 
                        $(this).text("Hide"); 
                    };
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The button color remains red, but appears totally different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a little change on your `$(this).toggleClass("btn btn-success");`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="inner">
                <h4>Topic Heading</h4>
                <p>This is the first paragraph in the topic.</p>
                <p>This is the second paragraph in the topic.</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Hide</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("button").click(function (){
                    $("#inner").toggle("slow");
                    if ($(this).text() == "Hide") {
                        $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass("btn-danger");
                        $(this).text("Show");
                    } 
                    else { 
                        $(this).addClass("btn-danger").removeClass("btn-success");
                        $(this).text("Hide"); 
                    };
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

in the if statement replace your code with:
 $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass('btn-danger');
in else,
$(this).addClass('btn-danger');

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="inner">
                <h4>Topic Heading</h4>
                <p>This is the first paragraph in the topic.</p>
                <p>This is the second paragraph in the topic.</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Hide</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("button").click(function (){
                    $("#inner").toggle("slow");
                    if ($(this).text() == "Hide") {
                        $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass('btn-danger');
                        $(this).text("Show");
                    } 
                    else { 
                        $(this).text("Hide"); 
                        $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
                    };
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```